# Allow listbox to display no results when ListBox.RowSource returns no results

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm currently populating a ListBox in a form with the following code:

```
'Populate In-Form Table
With ListBox_InFormTable
   .ColumnCount = 4
   .ColumnWidths = "100;100;100;50"
   .RowSource = ws.Range("MasterDataTable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
End With
```

However, I'm also actively filtering what's displayed in the listbox with other fields in the form.  This works fine except when I filter out all the results.  Instead of getting an error that states: "No cells were found." I'd rather just leave the in-form table blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been banging my head against this one for a while now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```
Dim n As Long
With ListBox_InFormTable
   .ColumnCount = 4
   .ColumnWidths = "100;100;100;50"
   On Error Resume Next
   n = ws.Range("MasterDataTable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
   On Error GoTo 0
   If n > 0 Then
    .RowSource = ws.Range("MasterDataTable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
   End If
End With
```

In case you are filtering an Excel Table, you may count the filtered rows as below...

```
Dim n As Long
With ListBox_InFormTable
   .ColumnCount = 4
   .ColumnWidths = "100;100;100;50"
   On Error Resume Next
   n = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterDataTable").Range.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
   On Error GoTo 0
   If n > 0 Then
    .RowSource = ws.Range("MasterDataTable").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
   End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work, however the code I'm using to filter the in-form listbox doesn't seem to be working consistently now.   
Here's the code:   
`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MasterDataTable").Range _  
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & TextBox_Employee.Value & "*"`

Comment: Added another piece of code, see if that works for you now.

Comment: It's hard to tell the cause behind the error without seen the data and the full code. Though I have provided solution to all the possible scenarios, you need to look at it yourself to see which method best works for you.